# When click notification, go to Mainactivity and resume the task (Countdown timer should continue) Android Studio

Tags: android, notifications

[**When use the below code, MainActivity resume. It's okey. But Two activity is running on background. SplashScreen and MainActivity. should Run only MainaActivity. How can I fix it ?  **](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JV3pM.jpg)

My goal is to notify the user at the time of purchase and when the `countdown` is over. The application was restarting when clicking on the `notification`. I tried `android: launchMode = "singleInstance" singleTop, singleTaskt` in `AndroidManifest`. It worked partially. but now both `SplashScreen` and `MainActivity` are opening in the background. Only `MainActivity` should be opened. How can I fix.

```
 **AndroidManifest.xml**
 <activity
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:name=".SplashScreen"
        android:configChanges="orientation"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation"
        android:launchMode="singleInstance"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:taskAffinity=""
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>


****Notification function in MainACtivity****
public void SendOnChannel1(String baslik, String icerik, boolean bildirimiptal){

    Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
   // resultIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN );
  //  resultIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
    resultIntent.setFlags( Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP );

    PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(MainActivity.this,0,resultIntent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_1_ID)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round)
            .setContentTitle(baslik)
            .setContentText(timeLeftFormatted)
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
            .setCategory(NotificationCompat.CATEGORY_REMINDER)
            .setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent)
            .setAutoCancel(bildirimiptal)
            .setOnlyAlertOnce(true)
            .build();


    notificationManager.notify(1,notification);




}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove Splash screen class & from Manifest file if it does nothing.

Answer (score -1):

To make it right you should first add a color to tour colors.xml

```
<color name="colorSplash">#FFC107</color>
```

Then you should create an xml file in your res/drawables folder. For example splash_background.xml and add the following;

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item
    android:drawable="@color/colorSplash"/>

<item>
    <bitmap
        android:gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/YOUR_LOGO"/>
</item>
```

Then you should define a theme in your styles.xml

```
<style name="SplashTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash_background</item>
</style>
```

After you finished the design you should edit your manifest file like this

```
<activity
        android:name=".SplashScreen"
        android:theme="@style/SplashTheme">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"/>
```

After that you should create a class(not activity!!!) named SplashScreen then edit this class like the following

```
public class SplashActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Intent intent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
}}
```

Pay attention here we didn't define any layout file here and add waiting time neither. Until MainActivity is prepared splash screen will be shown to the user. Hope this will be your problem. Kolay gelsin..

Comment: This code works, thank you. But when the application is open, clicking the icon again makes a very fast transition.

Comment: The code above is just to show splash screen while the activity is prepared. It has no layout and defined as launcher so every time you resume your app you are going to see this screen in very short time while android os is getting your application from back stack to front. By the way can you mark my solution as an answer if it works for you?